# Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas due to corporate proxy

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm building a MERN stack application. While using a personal network the connection made to MongoDB atlas works fine, however when I work at office I'm unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas due to corporate proxy.
I keep getting the following error:

```
err MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
```

PS: I've whitelisted my corporate IP address and have also tried network access from anywhere option but I keep getting the same error on corporate network

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and was not able to connect despite setting any Ip to network setting , I shared mobile internet then it did connect to db

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).